# USB Sound Card not detecting microphone

Tags: 14.04, usb, microphone, soundcard

I don't know why my USB sound card won't work on my Ubuntu 14.04. I mean I can hear sound from my headset but my problem is the microphone. Whenever I tried to record my voice, there was nothing being recorded. I don't know why this is happening on Ubuntu. I tried it on Windows 7 and it works. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Have you checked the input level in alsa settings, sometimes its way down, sometimes its muted.

Comment: @KenMollerup Yeah I did that and it still wasn't working.

Comment: Can you do a `hardinfo --generate-report > /tmp/hardinfo.txt` and post the output to http://paste.ubuntu.com